# Magento soap api login failed using PHP

Tags: php, magento, soap

I am working with magento soap api and  it's works fine in my local machine and development server but when i moved my code to production server i found the following error:

**Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://www.mydomain.com/magento/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1' : failed to load external entity "http://www.mydomain.com/magento/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1" Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__call('login', Array) #1**

I have also check the SOAP setting on server everything is OK but still this error comes.

Please help me...!

Answer (score 0):

I confronted the same problem.
I used V2 Soap.
So to create SoapClient, please try .../api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1
Hope this helps you.